# Do I need to provide multiple db instance if I enable MultiAZ in Aurora?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am reading this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html about high available for Aurora. It supports Multi-AZ configuration for db instance in Aurora cluster. Based on the doc, `Amazon RDS automatically provisions and maintains a synchronous standby replica in a different Availability Zone`, does this mean it creates one db instance per AZ in the region?

In my current configuration, I have three db instance `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` and each one is provisioned in one AZ. Do I still need to create three instance? Can one instance do the job? I understand multiple readers help on high throughput and performance. But in terms of High available, do I still need to provide three instances for three AZ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the **wrong link** for MultiAZ. Your link is for MultiAZ in RDS, not Aurora. This is important because in Aurora there is **no standby replica**. MultiAZ in Aurora works differently then in RDS.

The correct links are [High availability for Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.html) and [Replication with Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html).

Basically, in Aurora, your Replicas are the source of its HA and MultiAZ. If Aurora writer fails, Aurora will **automatically** promote one of its Replicas to be new writer.

> Can one instance do the job?

No it can't. For Aurora you need at least one Replcia.

> I understand multiple readers help on high throughput and performance.

Not only this. Replicas provide fail-over capabilities for Aurora.

> But in terms of High available, do I still need to provide three instances for three AZ?

Three are not needed. Minimum is two - writer in one AZ, and replica in a second AZ.